# Showing a series equality.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to show
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{t^k}{k!}}\right)-\frac{1+\frac{t}{2}}{1-\frac{t}{2}}=O(t^3)$$

So I tried using the geometric series:
$$=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{t^k}{k!}}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1+\frac{t}{2})\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^k$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{t^k}{k!}}-\left(\frac{2+t}{2}\right)\frac{t^k}{2^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{t^k}{k!}}-\frac{(2+t)t^k}{2^{k+1}}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{2^{k+1}t^k-k!(2+t)t^k}{k!2^{k+1}}}$$
But here I'm stucked.

Comment: You just need to check that the Taylor series of $\frac{1+t/2}{1-t/2}$ match the Taylor series of the exponential function for the terms $t^0, t^1, t^2$. And that is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Technically, this isn't true, unless you specify "for $t$ near $0$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. To show that it is $O(t^3)$ all you need to do is show that the coefficients on $t^0, t^1$ and $t^2$ are $0$. You should start by making sure each term has the same power of $t$ in it:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{2^{k+1}t^k - k!(2 + t)t^k}{k!2^{k+1}} &= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{2^{k+1}t^k - 2k!t^k - k!t^{k+1}}{k!2^{k+1}} \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{2^k} \right)t^k - \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}t^{k+1} \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{2^k} \right)t^k - \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k}}t^{k} \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{0!} - \frac{1}{2^0} \right)t^0 + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} \right)t^k.
\end{align*}
$$

Now plug in $k = 1, 2$ into the sum on the right to show that those coefficients are 0 and also verify that $1/0! - 1/2^0 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I like this one the most, since it uses my approach.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1+t/2}{1-t/2}
=\left(1+\frac t2\right)\left(1+\frac t2+\frac{t^2}4+\frac{t^3}8+\cdots\right)=1+t+\frac{t^2}2+\frac{t^3}4+\cdots.$$
Subtracting from $e^t$ gives $t^3/12+\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comment above, you only have this relationship for $t$ bounded (or "near zero.") Specifically, it is true in the interval $(-1,1)$. It becomes problematic when $t$ is near $2$ and as $t\to\infty$, so, for example, it is not true on the interval $(-2,2)$ or the interval $(3,\infty)$.

It's easier to expand the second part if you notice that $$\frac{1+\frac{t}{2}}{1-\frac{t}{2}}=\frac{2}{1-\frac{t}{2}}-1$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ok I see I assume $t$ should be near $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\frac{1+\frac t2}{ 1-\frac t2}&=\left(1+\frac t2\right)\left(1+\frac t2+\frac{t^2}{4} +\frac{t^3}8+\ldots\right)\\&=1+(\tfrac12+\tfrac12)t+(\tfrac14+\tfrac14)t^2+O(t^3)\\&=\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}t+\frac1{2!}t^2+O(t^3)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, very few steps for the solution, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Without the exp function, without Taylor, without series expansions: Writing the terms gives

$$
\frac{(1-t/2)(1 + t + t^2/2 + t^3/6 + \cdots) -1-\frac{t}{2}}{1-\frac{t}{2}}= \\
\frac{(1 + t + t^2/2 + t^3/6 - t/2 - t^2/2 - t^3/4 + O(t^4)) -1-\frac{t}{2}}{1-\frac{t}{2}}= \\
\frac{O(t^3)}{1-\frac{t}{2}}= O(t^3)
$$

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer!